# Entity Framework adding record twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my first post on stack so sorry for any inconvenience or my bad English.
I'm having a problem with Entity Framework `SaveChanges()` adding new `User` record twice into the database table.

I've created a `UserFormViewModel` for posting data based on user inputs from modal window form.

This is my `UserFormViewModel`:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public byte UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

All inputs from the view are mapped correctly to `AddOrEdit` action method parameter, so problem starts when saving the data into the database via `SaveChanges()` method. It's adding record twice into the table.

- I've tried adding `User` separately and it adds that `User` twice.
- Then I've tried adding the `Address` separately and it adds `Address` twice.
- When saving `User` and `Address` in one `dbContext` instance or in two separated `dbContext` instances, `User` and `Address` are again added twice.

Also tried database first approach but results are the same.

I'm assuming it has to do with relationships between the tables but can't point to the right cause.

In `Address` model class there are standard properties for street address:

```
 Id, StreetName, StreetNumber, Zip, City
```

and two foreign keys:

```
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public int? ShopId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
```

So `User` and `Shop` share `Address` table for their addresses.

Another way around when `User` and `Shop` are set to reference `Address` table all works fine.

But I want to understand why this is not working and in the end to make `Address` be able to cascade on `User` or `Shop` delete instead of using LINQ to remove `Address`.

Here is the action method `AddOrEdit` for a `User` and its `Address`:

```
private readonly FurnitureStoreDbContext _context;
    
public UsersController()
{
    _context = new FurnitureStoreDbContext();
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    _context.Dispose();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(UserFormViewModel userForm)
{
    if (userForm.Id == 0)
    {
        var newUser = new User
                          {
                              Username = userForm.Username,
                              Password = userForm.Password,
                              Name = userForm.Name,
                              Surname = userForm.Surname,
                              Email = userForm.Email,
                              UserRoleId = userForm.UserRoleId
                          };

        _context.tblUsers.Add(newUser);

        _context.SaveChanges();

        var newAddress = new Address
            {
                StreetName = userForm.Address.StreetName,
                StreetNumber = userForm.Address.StreetNumber,
                ZipCode = userForm.Address.ZipCode,
                City = userForm.Address.City,
                UserId = newUser.Id
            };

        _context.tblStreetAddresses.Add(newAddress);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        var updatedUser = new User
            {
                Username = userForm.Username,
                Password = userForm.Password,
                Name = userForm.Name,
                Surname = userForm.Surname,
                Email = userForm.Email,
                UserRoleId = userForm.UserRoleId
            };

        var updatedAddress = userForm.Address;

        _context.Entry(updatedUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _context.Entry(updatedAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Updated" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Here is a debug log for adding only `User` - without adding `Address`.

`Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Users__536C85E479927847'` exception is happening because I've set `Username` field to be unique and context is trying to add `User` record twice.

```
Step into: Stepping over property 'FurnitureStore.Models.User.get_Addresses'. To step into properties or operators, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
Step into: Stepping over property 'FurnitureStore.Models.User.get_Addresses'. To step into properties or operators, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
Opened connection at 3/27/2021 8:55:09 PM +01:00
Opened connection at 3/27/2021 8:55:09 PM +01:00
Started transaction at 3/27/2021 8:55:09 PM +01:00
Started transaction at 3/27/2021 8:55:09 PM +01:00
INSERT [dbo].[Users]([Username], [Password], [Name], [Surname], [Email], [UserRoleId])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Users]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()INSERT [dbo].[Users]([Username], [Password], [Name], [Surname], [Email], [UserRoleId])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Users]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()

-- @0: 'Username 1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @0: 'Username 1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @1: 'q1w2e3r4' (Type = String, Size = 20)
-- @2: 'Name 1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @3: 'Surname 1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @4: 'jjee@gmail.com' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- @5: '2' (Type = Byte, Size = 1)
-- Executing at 3/27/2021 8:55:10 PM +01:00
-- @1: 'q1w2e3r4' (Type = String, Size = 20)
-- @2: 'Name 1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @3: 'Surname 1' (Type = String, Size = 50)
-- @4: 'jjee@gmail.com' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- Completed in 7 ms with result: SqlDataReader

-- @5: '2' (Type = Byte, Size = 1)
-- Executing at 3/27/2021 8:55:10 PM +01:00
Committed transaction at 3/27/2021 8:55:10 PM +01:00
-- Failed in 26 ms with error: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Users__536C85E479927847'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (Username 1).
The statement has been terminated.

Closed connection at 3/27/2021 8:55:10 PM +01:00
Closed connection at 3/27/2021 8:55:10 PM +01:00
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' in EntityFramework.dll
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

The thread 0x42cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: That code looks fine.  You're probably running the controller twice, or already have that user in your database.  And you've got a bug on the "update" branch in that you don't set the user's ID on the entity before trying to update.

Comment: `updatedUser` doesn't have an `Id` value set (while the database table clearly has the field). That should cause trouble updating, but no a re-insert, the way you coded it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting adding and updating into separate actions, as it's easy to configure the appropriate link in the UI via Razor etc.

In any case your issue is with your update logic. When working with EF DbContexts you should seek to retrieve the entity when updating.  For example:

```
var existingUser = _context.Users
    .Include(x => x.Address)
    .Single(x => x.UserId == userForm.Id);
```

From here, copy across the fields from your UserForm that you allow to be edited. For instance if they can change their name, surname, and email:

```
existingUser.Name = userForm.Name;
existingUser.Surname = userForm.Surname;
existingUser.Email = userForm.Email;
```

The benefit of this approach is that EF will only generate an UPDATE statement for the fields that actually change, and only if at least one actually changes. Using the `Update()` method or setting an entity's state to `Modified` will result in an UPDATE statement for **all** columns, even if nothing actually changed.

The next issue will be with references. When using view models, entities should never be passed to the view. Code like this is generally problematic:

```
var updatedAddress = userForm.Address;
_context.Entry(updatedUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This makes a lot of dangerous assumptions that the userForm.Address points to a valid record, and that the DbContext isn't already tracking an entity with that ID.

In the previous example statement that fetched the user from the DbContext, I eager loaded the address. This way instead of passing an Address entity in your UserForm view model, pass a POCO view model for the address details and you can use that to edit or insert an address as needed:

```
if (existingUser.Address != null)
{
    existingUser.Address.AddressLine1 = userForm.Addres.AddressLine1;
    // ...
}
else
{
    var address = new Address
    {
        AddressLine1 = userForm.Addres.AddressLine1;
        // ...
    };
    existingUser.Address = address;
}
```

It's quite important to fetch references when dealing with many-to-many or many-to-one relationships like when associating Users to Shops. From the user perspective when associating to a shop, the Shop entity should already exist, so fetching it from the DbContext by ID serves as a validation that the ShopId is valid, and also avoids situations where you end up unintentionally inserting duplicate rows.

Lastly, only call `SaveChanges()` once. This ensures that changes made to the various related entities only happen all together or not at all.

It is possible to update entities by using methods like `Update` and `Attach` /w EntityState however this method is quite error prone and can lead to intermittent / situational runtime errors in cases where the DbContext could be already tracking an entity when you use something like `Attach` or `Update` on a new instance with the same ID.  As mentioned it also leads to less efficient UPDATE SQL statements and can leave your system vulnerable to unintended tampering.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake sorry. I forgot to type return false in onSubmit(form) function, so form was submitted twice. All the time I was focusing on C# code. Anyway your suggestions improved my code and prevented future errors so thank you very much for your time and effort everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I'd add my personal experience and fix.  I was having an issue with all of my calls being posted twice but only in firefox. The issue turned out to be the way firefox and iis communicate.  The way I solved was by disabling HTTP/2 in the https binding settings inside IIS. I only discovered the solution after a day looking through code for a blank href or src somewhere.